# Jersey endpoint using '+' in queryparam

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I want to design an endpoint similar to

```
$host/api/products?price=under+5
```

How can I use '+' in queryparam?

I could do like this to get that url

```
@GET
@Path("/products?price=under+{price}")
```

But How can I do using @QueryParam? If I use the following,

```
@GET
@Path("/products")
@UnitOfWork
public Response getProducts(@NotNull @QueryParam("price") String price) {
```

I get

```
$host/api/products?price=5
```

Comment: Please let me know if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579396/1426227) works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `price` query parameter must be *URL encoded*. When URL encoded, the `+` character becomes `%2B`. So you'll have `under%2B5`.

With it, the following should work fine:

```java
@GET
@Path("/products")
public Response getProducts(@NotNull @QueryParam("price") String price) {
    // the value of price will be: under+5
    ...
}
```

If you don't want the JAX-RS runtime to decode the `price` parameter, annotate it with [`@Encoded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Encoded.html).